# responsability for making a new instance in object composition

Tags: java

So, if you have a collection of objects in a class. And you want to add some objects to that collection. Which way is more accurate?

This way:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main (String args []){
        A aIntance = A();
        B bIntance =B();
        String rawData = "id=123,name=Bdude";
        String id,name;
        //do something to get the id and name from rawData...
        //done.
        //now we just make the object.
        bIntance = new B(id,name);
        aIntance.addB(bIntance); //A JUST add the object to his collection.
    }
}
class A{
    private List<B> b_list;
    public void addB(B bIntance){
        b_list.add(bIntance);
    }
}

class B{
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

Or this one:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String args []){
        A aIntance = A();
        aIntance.addB("id= 123,name=I'm B"); //A do the job of create the B object. 
    }
}
class A{
    private List<B> b_list;
    public void addB(String rawData){
        String id,name;
        //do something to get the id and name from rawData...
        //done.
        //now we just make the object.
        B myB = new B(id,name);
        b_list.add(myB);
    }
}

class B{
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

In the first:

- If the B class definition changes, you don't have to modify the addB method from A. But if you want to add multiple objects at the same time you will have to deal with the problem by yourself.

In the second one:

- The client give the necessary information (rawData) to A, and A do the job of make the object and can have a "addMultipleB" method where u just pass an Array of String with the "rawData". But, this make A more susceptible to errors (if Rawdata is not correct) and fragile to any modification in B.

So, which one is the more OO correctly option?

Comment: Side note: your B class is missing a reasonable equals()/hashCode() method implementation. Doesn't matter for lists, but as soon as you start using B objects for comparisons (for example when putting them in maps/sets), unexpected things will start to happen.

Comment: @Jägermeister i didn't notice that, thanks!

Comment: The other thing: consider making your B's immutable. Meaning: make its fields final; and only allow setting them via constructor.

Comment: @Jägermeister  i can't see why, and if a need to change something in a B object? what i do in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As so often on such broad questions, the answer is: it depends.

If: your class B is something internal, that you only want to use within that class A, or maybe within a few classes in a small package, then you might go with option 2.

But in general, option 1 is to be preferred: you see, if you are using a B class to "model" something that represents a "B object" ... then **all** of your code should be using B objects. The point is: your B class adds an abstraction. It isn't now, but it could be easily extended to be more than just a combination of int/string. Meaning: it is a bad idea that some of your "B related" data exists as true B objects, whereas the others might be hanging around as "raw strings".

Finally: keep in mind the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles; and right there, the first one (single responsibility principle) gives you a hint - in the sense of: turning a raw string into a B, and storing Bs, and so on ... are probably different responsibilities; and should then probably go into different classes.

Answer (score 2):

I belive the name of the function is misleading in the second case. It should be something like: `createAndAddNewBInstance`. Also the second approach makes the `A` class depending on implementation of class `B`.

If you want to create a connection between these two classes it would be more reasonable to create a `static` function in `B` class that takes `rawData` and reference to `A` instance, creates a new `B` instance and adds it to `A` via `addB`.

```
class B {
    static void createNewInstanceAndAddToA(String rawData, A aInstance){...}
    ...
}
```

This way your implementation details of `B` are within the `B` class scope. You could also extract an `interface` from `A` with `addB` to make it more `SOLID`.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you think you will never need to use a B instance in the main method (in Test class), the second approach is more clean and readable, but if you think there will be a need in the future to use a B instance in "Test" class, you better instantiate B there.